# If b is the mean proportional between a and c.

Tags: linear-algebra

If *b* is the *mean proportional* between *a* and *c*. Show that *b(a + c)* is the mean proportion between ($a^2 +b^2)$  and $(b^2 +c^2)$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)=(a^2+ac)(ac+c^2)=a^3c+2a^2c^2+ac^3=ac(a+c)^2=b^2(a+c)^2$$

Comment: You probably could have skipped the $a^3c+2a^2c^2+ac^3$ step, since it's easy enough to factor an $a$ out of $a^2+ac$ and a $c$ out of $ac+c^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Practicing for finals which are in the coming week.